# Accounts.onLogin throws session not found error

Tags: meteor, exception, redirect, meteor-accounts, flow-router

The `LoggedInUser` works well as it is suppose but whenever the app starts and the URL is queried like trying to login or navigate to any other URL, the `Accounts.onLogin` throws the below error. I don't know what could be the reason.

```
var LoggedInUser = FlowRouter.group({
  name: 'currentUser', triggersEnter: [function () {
    if (!Meteor.loggingIn() || !Meteor.userId()) {
      var currentRoute = FlowRouter.current();
      if (!currentRoute.route.name === 'home') {
        console.log(currentRoute.path);
          Session.set('redirectAfterLogin', currentRoute.path);
      }
      FlowRouter.go('home');
    }
  }]
});

Accounts.onLogin(function () {
  let redirect = Session.get('redirectAfterLogin');
  if (redirect) {
    if (redirect != 'home') {
      FlowRouter.go(redirect);
    }
  }
});
```

Error on cmd console

```
I20171003-18:28:44.913(1)? Exception in onLogin callback: ReferenceError: Session is not defined
I20171003-18:28:44.919(1)?     at lib/routes/routes.js:30:18
I20171003-18:28:44.921(1)?     at runAndHandleExceptions (packages\callback-hook.js:152:24)
I20171003-18:28:44.926(1)?     at packages\callback-hook.js:159:12
I20171003-18:28:44.931(1)?     at packages/accounts-base/accounts_server.js:164:5
I20171003-18:28:44.934(1)?     at [object Object]._.extend.each (packages\callback-hook.js:128:15)
I20171003-18:28:44.938(1)?     at AccountsServer.Ap._successfulLogin (packages/accounts-base/accounts_server.js:163:21)
I20171003-18:28:44.943(1)?     at AccountsServer.Ap._attemptLogin (packages/accounts-base/accounts_server.js:353:10)
I20171003-18:28:44.946(1)?     at [object Object].methods.login (packages/accounts-base/accounts_server.js:530:21)
I20171003-18:28:44.949(1)?     at packages\check.js:128:16
I20171003-18:28:44.953(1)?     at [object Object].EVp.withValue (packages\meteor.js:1135:15)
```

Answer (score 0):

The onLogin function you are using needs the Session package according to the following line :

```
  let redirect = Session.get('redirectAfterLogin');
```

The error in the console states than the Session package can not be found. Please make sure of the following:

1. Meteor Session is installed. If not please install it with:

   ```
   meteor add Session
   ```

in your terminal in your project folder.

2. Session is imported in the file you want to use it, if not please add at the top of your file :

   ```
   import { Session } from 'meteor/session'
   ```